# react jest mock useNavigate()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-hooks, react-router-dom

```
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-alpha.5",
```

I have tried nearly everything.

I just want to mock this `navigate()` call from the `useNavigate()` hook. that's it. Simple. Nothing working.

**No, i do not want to use `Link`. useNavigate is used programmatically in other places as well and I want to mock them too**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

export const Detail = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <span onClick={() => navigate('/some/specific/route')}>
            some Text
        </span>
    )
}
```

I have tried these:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
    // Require the original module to not be mocked...
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        // add your noops here
        useNavigate: jest.fn(() => 'bar')
    };
});
```

```
import * as ReactRouterDom from "react-router-dom";
...
// cannot redefine property
          Object.defineProperty(ReactRouterDom, 'useNavigate', {
              configurable: true,
              value: jest.fn(() => 'bar')
          });
```

```
// doesnt work
          jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
              useNavigate: jest.fn(() => jest.fn),
          }))
```

```
// doesnt work
jest.spyOn(ReactRouterDom, 'useNavigate', 'get').mockReturnValue(jest.fn(() => jest.fn));
```

```
// doesnt work
jest.spyOn(ReactRouterDom, 'useNavigate').mockReturnValue(jest.fn(() => jest.fn));
```

```js
// doesnt work
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));
```

all of these either show `"Cannot redefine Property 'useNavigate'"`, or that     `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Seriously, any other import mock works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

MY MINIMUM RECREATED PROJECT: https://github.com/zacharytyhacz/useNavigateBug

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had a similar concern that was fixed  with [this issue from react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7811)

I would suggest you  change the mock as is:

```js
// pay attention to write it at the top level of your file
const mockedUsedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as any,
  useNavigate: () => mockedUsedNavigate,
}));


// your describe/it/test blocks go down there
```

Comment: What error did it throw? Can you point to your example repo or show your test file?

Comment: it says same error in original post `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

Comment: Mind pasting your test file?

Comment: Here's my minimal project of the issue: https://github.com/zacharytyhacz/useNavigateBug

Comment: Your mokedUseNavigate and jest mock(https://github.com/zacharytyhacz/useNavigateBug/blob/86ac42296a07af65f15ca1298817add5ac486310/tests/Home.test.tsx#L63) should be at the top level of the file, not inside "test", "it" or "describe": See this for reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7811

Comment: can you edit your answer / post new answer mentiong that?, I gotchu on this bounty

Comment: @Zac please try render(<BrowserRouter><YourComponent /></BrowserRouter>)

Comment: Working, THX a lot.

Comment: Why does the `jest.mock('react-router-dom'...` have to be at the top level of the file?

Comment: I already have that implementation but I can't make the navigate mock to be called. Here it is all the [details of my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478724/usenavigate-from-react-router-dom-not-called-when-testing-with-jest). Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28):

Here's how I mock and assert on `navigate()` calls in my component tests:

```js
import * as router from 'react-router'

const navigate = jest.fn()

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate').mockImplementation(() => navigate)
})

it('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path')
})
```

Comment: Testing implementation is only a workaround and is advised against mostly, but since I can't make it work with the accepted answer, I'll have to use such approach...

Comment: @Enfieldli totally agree. However, there are situations where your component might do a redirect via `navigate()` when it receives certain prop(s). For such situations asserting on a call to `navigate()` in a unit test is totally fine, imo. On the other hand, for navigation events done via clicking, testing it a higher level (via cypress, for example) is advised.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to spy on `useNavigate` normally if you change your import from:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
```

to

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router"
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Otherwise I was blocked by     
`TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useNavigate
 at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)`

Answer (score 3):

I'm using React testing Library. Per the documentation, I have a test utils file which exports a custom render method. The custom render method wraps the rendered component in mocked providers *as well as a router*. This enables me to do the following:

```
 it('redirects when span is clicked', async () => {
    const span = await screen.findByText('some text')
    await userEvent.click(span)
    await waitFor(() => expect(window.location.href).toContain('/some/sepcific/route'))
  })
```

To be fair, it's a different approach than what the OP asked specifically about. However, I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: This answer saved me, at least for now.